# iOS: Send http request/ read http response

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I need to authenticate my iPhone app on the website. Is there a pattern for sending http request and reading http response?

I need to be able to get to know if the login/password are wrong from server rejection and show it on iPhone, any directions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use the NSUrlConnection APi. It does exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The ASIHTTPRequest library works really well at making a lot of what you are talking about fairly easy. Check it out at [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use)